# Error when compiling azerothcore on debian 9

Tags: azerothcore

The compiling process breaks at around 11%. I'm inside the azerothcore/build/ directory and running the command

```
make -j4
```

Errors are included below.

```
      ^
23 warnings and 1 error generated.
29 warnings and 1 error generated.
src/server/shared/CMakeFiles/shared.dir/build.make:120: recipe for target 'src/server/shared/CMakeFiles/shared.dir/Realms/RealmList.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/server/shared/CMakeFiles/shared.dir/Realms/RealmList.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
src/server/shared/CMakeFiles/shared.dir/build.make:81: recipe for target 'src/server/shared/CMakeFiles/shared.dir/DataStores/DBCDatabaseLoader.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/server/shared/CMakeFiles/shared.dir/DataStores/DBCDatabaseLoader.cpp.o] Error 1
7 warnings generated.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:943: recipe for target 'src/server/shared/CMakeFiles/shared.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/server/shared/CMakeFiles/shared.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:148: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm using these version of gcc and cmake.
gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
cmake 3.18.2

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler version is too old. Try a newer version of `gcc` or `clang`.

You need AT LEAST `gcc` 7.5+ or `clang` 6, however the latest stable version is recommended.